# "Files changed" on Github show different code in grey than currently in repository

Tags: git, github

I am looking into this [commit on Github](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/2285/files), and I am curious as to why the supposedly unchanged text in grey in the "Files changed" pane is different from the content in the [branch that the commit is aimed at](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master).

See for instance the method `void NesterovSolver<Dtype>::ComputeUpdateValue(int param_id, Dtype rate)`. In the branch repostiory [the file](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/solver.cpp) with the method does not contain the line `Dtype rate = this->GetLearningRate();` although it is clearly marked with grey as line 616 in the commit.

How can that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the [branch of kevinbache](https://github.com/kevinbache/caffe/tree/record_grad_norm), you'll notice that GitHub says:

> This branch is 2 commits ahead, 210 commits behind BVLC:master

He branched some time in April ([13 March version of solver.cpp from BVLC](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/e46cf85544ab8c4b40d529cd31e9b890a4fce19a/src/caffe/solver.cpp)) and didn't pull BVLC's commits since then so at that time, the lines were still in there. What you see in the Pull Request is the diff of kevinbache's versions before and after his changes with his files' context. But only the differences will be applied to BVLC's code, the context lines are ignored.